# CSS Transition from Animated State

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Is it possible to force an element with an animation property affecting opacity to transition from its current state to another predetermined state on hover?

The null state object is animating between differing opacities:

```
    #thumb {
    opacity: .33;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2.7s infinite ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: pulse 2.7s infinite ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: pulse 2.7s infinite ease-in-out; 
    -moz-animation: pulse 2.7s infinite ease-in-out; 
    animation: pulse 2.7s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { opacity: 0.23; }
    50% { opacity: 0.42; }
    100% { opacity: 0.23; }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% { opacity: 0.23; }
    50% { opacity: .42; }
    100% { opacity: .23; }
}
```

And I would like it ease in to a different image and opacity on hover state:

```
#thumb:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(hover.png); 
    -webkit-animation: initial;
    -o-animation: initial;
    -ms-animation: initial; 
    -moz-animation: initial; 
    animation: initial;
    -webkit-transition: .23s ease-in-out;
    transition: .23s ease-in-out;
}
```

I've been able to achieve a direct jump to opacity:1;, but haven't been able to achieve the smooth transition.

A prototype can be found here, on Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqmMEV

Comment: no you cannot with CSS

Comment: if you can't provide a working example of your code we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

add transition to the `#thumb` style, you currently only apply it to it's hover style so you will not see a transition

```
#thumb{
   transition: .23s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I apologize for not mentioning it, but #thumb is currently inheriting that rule

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.net or codepen.io demo so I can see a working example?